# Split String based on Shrinking Sliding Window/ 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create fragments of A string on multiple delimiters.
For Example I have the following String.

Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia :: Small Lymphocytic Lymphoma

I need to split the String first based on this delimiter ::

That part is easy.

The from each of the substrings(Term) I need to generate fragments based on the following rule

A term composed of words A, B and C, i.e., 'A B C' is fragmented into 
'A B C' (0), 'A B' (1), 'B C' (2), 'A' (3), 'B' (4), 'C' (5)

A term length is not fixed. It can be three words or more or less.

logic is that each word in the term should only be concatenated to next words in the array in a shrinking window logic. So first word is A and it has B C after it. So combination will be A B C. then window shrinks from right to left so next Combo will be A B and next will be C.

FOR  so in case of a term A B C D the output fragments will be

'A B C D'
'A B C',
'A B',
'A',
'B C D',
'B C',
'B',
'C D',
'C',
'D'

and in case of a term A B C D E the output fragments will be

'A B C D E','A B C D', 'A B C', 'A B','A', 'B C D E','B C D', 'B C,'B','C D E','C D','C','D E','D','E'

In the above "Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia" and "Small Lymphocytic Lymphoma" are two terms.

The output for Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia I need is

Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia
Chronic Lymphocytic
Chronic
Lymphocytic Leukemia
Lymphocytic
Leukemia

I am trying to split this into a 2D array and then iterate through them and try to concatenate them but I am hitting a road block

```
String str="Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia :: Small Lymphocytic Lymphoma";
String[] rows=str.split("::");
String[][] table=new String[rows.length][];
for (int i=0; i<rows.length;i++)
  {
     table[i]=rows[i].split(" ");
  }

for (int i=0;i<table.length;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<table[i].length;j++)
      {
        System.out.println(table[i][j]);
      }
  }
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this

Comment: The Length of the TERM Is not fixed. It can be less or more than 3 Digits. A B C is just an example.

In case of 4 letter term A B C D, output should be 
A B C D  <br/>
B C D  <br/>
C D<br/>
A<br/>
B<br/>
C<br/>
D<br/>

Each word of the term should only be concatenated with only the words after it.

Comment: Then you also need to tell us how these rules would scale for 4, 5, 6, etc. terms.

Comment: "*next Combo will be A B and next will be C*" is at least confusing if not wrong - by example it should be "`A B` and next will be `B C`" or? (and I would strongly recommend dividing the problem by doing the *permutation* in an own method, given the words and returning the *fragments*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost straight-forward:

- a loop that *selects* the first word;
- a second loop inside the first one that *selects* the final word, going backwards.
- inside that loop you just need to join the words an add to the result

Something like:

```
List<String> fragments(String[] words) {
    var result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (var j = words.length; j > i; j--) {
            result.add(Arrays.stream(words, i, j).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
        }
    }
    // result.remove(0);  // if you don't want the whole sequence inside the result
    return result;
}
```

If, for some reason, `stream` is not an option, a third loop is needed to collect the words:

```
List<String> fragments(String[] words) {
    var result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (var j = words.length; j > i; j--) {
            var fragment = new StringBuilder();
            for (var k = i; k < j; k++) {
                if (k > i) {
                    fragment.append(" ");
                }
                fragment.append(words[k]);
            }
            result.add(fragment.toString());
        }
    }
    // result.remove(0);  // if you dont want the whole sequence inside the result
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the answer

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String[] array= {"a","b","c","d", "e"};
      HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<>(); 

       for (int i=0; i<array.length  ; i++){ 

           addWords(array, i, result);
       }
    }

    public static void addWords(String[]array, int n, Set<String> result){
         int wordSize = array.length - n;
         //need to loop wordSize number of times.
        int numberOfLoops = array.length -wordSize +1 ;

         System.out.println("Handling n="+n+" wordsize="+wordSize+", numLoops="+numberOfLoops);

         for (int i = 0; i< numberOfLoops; i++){
             String word ="";
             for(int j = i; j<wordSize+i; j++){
                 word+=array[j]+" ";
             } 
             result.add(word.trim());

             System.out.println("Adding: "+ word);
         }
    }
}
```

the expected result is as follows.

```
Handling n=0 wordsize=5, numLoops=1
Adding: a b c d e 
Handling n=1 wordsize=4, numLoops=2
Adding: a b c d 
Adding: b c d e 
Handling n=2 wordsize=3, numLoops=3
Adding: a b c 
Adding: b c d 
Adding: c d e 
Handling n=3 wordsize=2, numLoops=4
Adding: a b 
Adding: b c 
Adding: c d 
Adding: d e 
Handling n=4 wordsize=1, numLoops=5
Adding: a 
Adding: b 
Adding: c 
Adding: d 
Adding: e
```

Comment: I used HashSet for the event of duplicates (e.g. array =  A, A, A). Change to a TreeSet if you need to sort it alphabetically. or plain old ArrayList if duplicates and order is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Regex replacement might be really helpful here.  We can try capturing each of the three terms in separate capture groups `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`.  Then, simply replace with these captured terms using the logic and order your want.

```
String str = "Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia :: Small Lymphocytic Lymphoma";
String[] rows = str.split("\\s+::\\s+");

for (String row : rows) {
    String output = row.replaceAll("(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+)", "$1 $2 $3 $1 $2 $2 $3 $1 $2 $3");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

This prints:

```
Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia Chronic Lymphocytic Lymphocytic Leukemia Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia
Small Lymphocytic Lymphoma Small Lymphocytic Lymphocytic Lymphoma Small Lymphocytic Lymphoma
```

Comment: I am not sure Regex would be a good idea, because. the le length of the words is not defined . It could be 3 words of 4. That is why I was trying to dynamic arrays since we are not sure if there are three words or more.

Comment: `A term composed of words A, B and C` ... did not you tell us the actual problem when you posted?

Comment: It was just an example. A term could be composed of more than 3 words. A B C was just an example.

For example for a term with A B C D
output would be  
A B C D,
B C D,
C D,
A

Comment: @Junaid388 If it is just an example and can be different, you should explicitly tell us that.  There is no way for us to know it can be different, you never said it could be.